# Logarithmic de Rham complex induced map on Hypercohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-topology

• Question: Assume X
  is an algebraic manifold over $\mathbb{C}$
  and $D$
  is a simple normal crossings divisor. The logarithmic de Rham complex $\left(\Omega_{X}^{\bullet}\left(log\ D\right),d\right)$
  (see for example Esnault-Viehweg, “Lectures on Vanishing Theorems”: 2.1, 2.2) is a complex whose terms are $\mathcal{O}_{X}$
  -modules, but whose differentials seem to be only $\mathbb{C}$
 -linear (for example $d\left(x_{1}dx_{2}\right)=dx_{1}\wedge dx_{2}$
  but $x_{1}d\left(dx_{2}\right)=0$
 ). Given another complex $\left(B^{\bullet},d^{\prime}\right)$
  and morphism of complexes $f^{\bullet}:\left(\Omega_{X}^{\bullet}\left(log\ D\right),d\right)\to\left(B^{\bullet},d^{\prime}\right)$
  I should have an induced map on hypercohomology. Given that the differentials d
  seem to be only $\mathbb{C}$
 -linear, what are my restrictions on defining $f^{\bullet}$
 ? id est, am I just thinking of each $f^{i}$
  as a map of $\mathbb{C}$
 -modules, or is there some additional structure I need to take into account?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Do everything in the category of sheaves of $\Bbb{C}$-vector spaces. Note that the usual de Rham complex (not logarithmic) is also not a complex of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.

Comment: Taking @abx's comment a bit further, even the topological de Rham complex is not a complex of modules over the ring of functions. That's the whole idea of derivations: they are linear only w.r.t. constants.

Comment: @abx , AlexDegtyarev thanks for the answers. This is what I was thinking, but it felt fishy to me for some reason since a lot of places just refer to it as a "complex of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules".